# Python Function Return

Tags: python, function

If I want to return more that one variable from a function in Python I have been doing the following:

```
def foo():
    firstName = 'Bob'
    lastName = 'Jones'
    return [firstName, lastName]
```

Then if I wanted to find only the first name I would do this

```
[firstName, dummy] = foo()
```

However, say I initially had the function

```
def fooInitial():
    firstName = 'Bob'
    return firstName
```

and I called this from many parts of my code, if I wanted to add the `lastName` as another output the way I have been doing, I would have to change everywhere else in my code that was calling it.

Is there a way to do something similar to Matlab where calling `a = foo()` gives me the first name (not the first and last in a list) and `[a,b]=foo()` gives me the first and last?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Add to your function argument with default value == False and if argument True return [firstName, lastName] and if False return firstName

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. You are better of either changing all the code calling `fooInitial()`, or by adding a *different* method that returns the two parameters and have `fooInitial()` use that method:

```
def barInitial():
    first_name, last_name = 'Bob', 'Jones'
    return first_name, last_name

def fooInitial():
    return barInitial()[0]
```

Note that you can just return a tuple instead of a list too; tuples only require a comma to define so the syntax is lighter (no need for square brackets). You can do the same when unpacking the returned value:

```
first_name, last_name = barInitial()
```

Comment: A `namedtuple` is probably not a bad idea - going on the returning multiple values part of the OP... (just can't be bothered to write an answer for it)

Comment: Yes, I like this. Changing the name of the initial function seems the best and easiest thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with all of your answer except for the first three words.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def foo(last=None):
    # current behaviour, change no code
    If not last:
        return 'bob'

    # new behaviour return first and last list
    return ['bob', 'jones']
```

The addition of the named keyword with a default argument gives you your current behaviour for code you don't want to change, and for new code where you want first and last returned you would use

```
first, last = foo(last=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I don't recommend it.

```
# WARNING: Breaks iteration over chars

class StrOrPair(str):
    def __new__(cls, name, lastname):
        return str.__new__(cls, name)

    def __init__(self, name, lastname):
        str.__init__(self, name)
        self.lastname = lastname

    # __iter__ is used for unpacking
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self
        yield self.lastname

def foo():
    return StrOrPair('Bob', 'Jones')

name = foo()
[first, second] = foo()

print(name) # Bob
print(first) # Bob
print(second) # Jones

# broken iteration over chars:
for c in name:
    print(c) # expect 'B', 'o', 'b' but get 'Bob', 'Jones'
```