# Unexpected python function return behavior

Tags: python, function

I am working on a function that usually returns 1 value, but sometimes returns 2 for similar reasons to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144722/python-function-return), and noticed some unexpected behavior best illustrated by this example:

```
def testfcn1(return_two=False):
    a = 10
    return a, a*2 if return_two else a

def testfcn2(return_two=False):
    a = 10
    if return_two:
        return a, a*2
    return a
```

I would expect both functions to behave the same way. testfcn2 works as expected:

```
testfcn2(False)
10

testfcn2(True)
(10, 20)
```

However, testfcn1 always returns two values, and just returns the first value twice if return_two is False:

```
testfcn1(False)
(10, 10)

testfcn1(True)
(10, 20)
```

Is there a rationale for this kind of behavior?

Comment: But do you _really_ want a function that sometimes returns an int & sometimes returns a tuple? That can get messy. If the number of values to be returned can vary, then _always_ return a tuple & let the caller call the tuple's `len` method. A possible exception to this pattern is returning `None` instead of a tuple, but even then you can return an empty tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `testfcn1` , the expressions are grouped as -

```
(a, (a*2 if return_two else a))           #This would always return a tuple of 2 values.
```

And not (what you thought it would be) -

```
(a, a*2) if return_two else a             #This can return a tuple if return_two is True otherwise a single value `a` .
```

If you wanted the second grouping of expressions, you have to use brackets as I have used above.

---

Example to show the difference -

```
>>> 10, 20 if True else 10
(10, 20)
>>> 10, 20 if False else 10
(10, 10)
>>>
>>>
>>> (10, 20) if False else 10
10
>>> (10, 20) if True else 10
(10, 20)
>>>
>>>
>>> 10, (20 if False else 10)
(10, 10)
>>> 10, (20 if True else 10)
(10, 20)
```

Answer (score 3):

It a simple issue of operator precedence. `return a, a*2 if return_two else a` if interpreted as `return a, (a*2 if return_two else a)`. You should use parenthesis in order to change precedence.

```
def testfcn1(return_two=False):
    a = 10
    return (a, a*2) if return_two else a
```